# Wiring ESP8266 and PN532

Tags: esp8266, library, wires

I'm trying the Android Hce example in [this PN532 library](https://github.com/elechouse/PN532). I can't find how to set SDA and SCL address in the code, so I tried connecting them in CLK and SD0 pins. The serial monitor gives me "Didn't find PN53x board". Can someone help me?

```cpp
    #if 0
      #include <SPI.h>
      #include <PN532_SPI.h>
      #include "PN532.h"

      PN532_SPI pn532spi(SPI, 10);
      PN532 nfc(pn532spi);
    #elif 1
      #include <PN532_HSU.h>
      #include <PN532.h>

      PN532_HSU pn532hsu(Serial1);
      PN532 nfc(pn532hsu);
    #else 
      #include <Wire.h>
      #include <PN532_I2C.h>
      #include <PN532.h>
    #endif

    void setup()
    {    
        Serial.begin(115200);
        Serial.println("-------Peer to Peer HCE--------");

        nfc.begin();

        uint32_t versiondata = nfc.getFirmwareVersion();
        if (! versiondata) {
          Serial.print("Didn't find PN53x board");
          while (1); // halt
        }

        // Got ok data, print it out!
        Serial.print("Found chip PN5"); Serial.println((versiondata>>24) & 0xFF, HEX); 
        Serial.print("Firmware ver. "); Serial.print((versiondata>>16) & 0xFF, DEC); 
        Serial.print('.'); Serial.println((versiondata>>8) & 0xFF, DEC);

        // Set the max number of retry attempts to read from a card
        // This prevents us from waiting forever for a card, which is
        // the default behaviour of the PN532.
        //nfc.setPassiveActivationRetries(0xFF);

        // configure board to read RFID tags
        nfc.SAMConfig();
    }

    void loop()
    {
      bool success;

      uint8_t responseLength = 32;

      Serial.println("Waiting for an ISO14443A card");

      // set shield to inListPassiveTarget
      success = nfc.inListPassiveTarget();

      if(success) {

         Serial.println("Found something!");

        uint8_t selectApdu[] = { 0x00, /* CLA */
                                  0xA4, /* INS */
                                  0x04, /* P1  */
                                  0x00, /* P2  */
                                  0x07, /* Length of AID  */
                                  0xF0, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, /* AID defined on Android App */
                                  0x00  /* Le  */ };

        uint8_t response[32];  

        success = nfc.inDataExchange(selectApdu, sizeof(selectApdu), response, &responseLength);

        if(success) {

          Serial.print("responseLength: "); Serial.println(responseLength);

          nfc.PrintHexChar(response, responseLength);

          do {
            uint8_t apdu[] = "Hello from Arduino";
            uint8_t back[32];
            uint8_t length = 32; 

            success = nfc.inDataExchange(apdu, sizeof(apdu), back, &length);

            if(success) {

              Serial.print("responseLength: "); Serial.println(length);

              nfc.PrintHexChar(back, length);
            }
            else {

              Serial.println("Broken connection?"); 
            }
          }
          while(success);
        }
        else {

          Serial.println("Failed sending SELECT AID"); 
        }
      }
      else {

        Serial.println("Didn't find anything!");
      }

      delay(1000);
    }

    void printResponse(uint8_t *response, uint8_t responseLength) {

       String respBuffer;

        for (int i = 0; i < responseLength; i++) {

          if (response[i] < 0x10) 
            respBuffer = respBuffer + "0"; //Adds leading zeros if hex value is smaller than 0x10

          respBuffer = respBuffer + String(response[i], HEX) + " ";                        
        }

        Serial.print("response: "); Serial.println(respBuffer);
    }

    void setupNFC() {

      nfc.begin();

      uint32_t versiondata = nfc.getFirmwareVersion();
      if (! versiondata) {
        Serial.print("Didn't find PN53x board");
        while (1); // halt
      }

      // Got ok data, print it out!
      Serial.print("Found chip PN5"); Serial.println((versiondata>>24) & 0xFF, HEX); 
      Serial.print("Firmware ver. "); Serial.print((versiondata>>16) & 0xFF, DEC); 
      Serial.print('.'); Serial.println((versiondata>>8) & 0xFF, DEC);

      // configure board to read RFID tags
      nfc.SAMConfig(); 
    }
```

Comment: For I2C the default pins to use are whatever are defined in your board configuration - probably pins 4 and 5 (to mirror A4 and A5 on the Uno). However your code is set up to use serial, not I2C.

Comment: I was doubting so, can you please tell me the exact wiring for serial? (Or for anything to make this code work). I'd like to even know how to get these information, usually I find the pinout in the define section (how should be done)

Comment: For serial connect it to the UART1 TX and RX pins. Where those are depends on what module you have.

Comment: I have connected SCK to CLK (on ESP8266), MSO and MOSI connected to D6 and D7. How should I set up this in code? I tried to changing SPI, but it doesn't work

Comment: What you wire to where, and what code you use, depends on what PN532 module you have and what ESP8266 module you have.

Comment: I have Elechouse PN532 Module V3 and a NodeMCU

Comment: [This one?](https://www.elechouse.com/elechouse/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=90_93&products_id=2205)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Set #if 1 and #elif 0.
Connected:
SCK to D5
MISO to D6
MOSI to D7
SS to D0 (and set it on pn532spi)